# Cant retrieve mysql data into a single string

Tags: php, mysql

I am have this query that is supposed to retrieve data from my mysql database and print is as a single string. To understand what i am looking for, the query is supposed to select the data and then print it as 1/23/45/67/89/10/11

```
------------------------------------
id  ussd_string session_id
------------------------------------
1   1       123456  
2   /23     123456
3   /45     123456
4   /67     123456
5   /89     123456
6   /10     123456
7   /11     123456
------------------------------------
```

PHP:

```
$query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$newussdString=$rows['ussd_string'];
}
$ussdString = $newussdString;
echo $ussdString;
```

When i execute the code, it only returns the first value which is 1. What's the problem with my code.

Comment: Someone will say that..I don't want to be one..But http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php .. That's the truth about mysql_query.. He is gone :( We don't have him anymore..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `echo` in the `while` loop. As is you overwrite the variable every time so you only get the last row outputting.

Try:

```
$query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $rows['ussd_string'];
}
```

or if you need each value later, use an array:

```
$query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$values[] = $rows['ussd_string'];
}
foreach($values as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

or concatenation:

```
$values = '';
$query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$values .= $rows['ussd_string'];
}
echo $values;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
   $query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$ussdString = "";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $newussdString=$rows['ussd_string'];
    $ussdString .= $newussdString;
}
echo $ussdString;
```

You need to concat strings with `.=`

**EDIT**
You can also concat string in database  query http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm

Answer (score 4):

This return only one value because you are not print the result inside the loop. This will always return you the last record.

You can use like that:

```
$query="(SELECT * FROM userleveltracking WHERE session_id = '123456' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 7)"; 

$result=mysql_query($query);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
   echo $rows['ussd_string']."<br>";
}
```

**Other solution** is that you can store the rows data into an array and than use where you need.

**Side note**:

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`, than you may not use PHP loop:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ussd_string ORDER BY id SEPARATOR '')
FROM userleveltracking 
WHERE session_id = '123456' 
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As you shown code above you are not appending strings to each other.In each iteration that creates new object and override the previous one.

```
$newussdString=$rows['ussd_string'];
```

in this line.